# Visual C++ 2010: ``unresolved token" LNK2020

Tags: c++-cli, token, linker-errors

I have a VC++ 2010 solution containing two projects: ProjectX and ProjectXTests. In the current configuration, ProjectX builds as a static library and ProjectXTests as a DLL intended to test various methods in ProjectX. Now, in ProjectX I have a class User with a method getUserName(), as follows:

```
// User.h
public ref class User
{
    public:
       User(String^ userName);
       String^ getUserName();
    private:
       String^ userName;
};
```

The constructor and method are implemented in User.cpp. In ProjectXTests, I have a class UserTests, which tests, among other things, the getUserName() method, in a, say, getUserNameTest() method. It is declared in UserTests.h and implemented as follows in UserTests.cpp:

```
// UserTests.cpp
#include "UserTests.h"
#include "User.h"

void UserTests::getUserNameTest()
{
    User^ testUser = gcnew User("name");
    Assert::AreEqual("name", testUser->getUserName());
}
```

In the project properties (Common Properties -> Framework and References) of ProjectXTests, I have added a reference to ProjectX. In VC++ Directories, I have added the appropriate directories for header files and library files. When building the solution, the header file "User.h" is found. However, I get a link error

```
error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000005) User::getUserName
```

The same thing happens for all other methods being tested. I just can't figure out why this happens. So far, the only thing I've found to work, is to include the file "User.cpp" instead of "User.h" in "UserTests.cpp", but this seems like cheating. Does anybody know what I might be missing?

Comment: I see a class definition for "class User" that has a method "String^ getUserName()".  Did you ever give an *implementation*?

Comment: As mentioned, the method (and the class constructor) are both implemented in User.cpp, yes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you have to include the code from `ProjectX` in `ProjectXTests`. This is not done by literally using the `#include` directive, instead the simplest is to add the source files from `ProjectX` to the `ProjectXTests` project workspace. If `ProjectX` is made as a static of dynamic library, then link with that instead.

Comment: OK, adding the source files from ProjectX to the ProjectXTests project works. ProjectX is made as a static library, so I was kind of aiming for your second solution. How exactly do I make my test project link with my static library?

Comment: @Nikolay In the project settings, you have a alternative `Linker` where you can add the library as a dependency. But if you have both projects in the same workspace, I think you should be able to add it as a reference or by simply dragging it into your project tree. I haven't worked with VisualStudio for some time, so I'm unsure about the specifics. But it has been answered here on SO before, so do a search, or on Google, to find out.

Comment: I had added the library as a dependency as you indicate. However, looking through things now, I noticed that under the Linker options, there was an Additional Library Directories. I guess I thought it was enough to add my library directory to the VC++ Directories, but now everything works as it should. Thanks a lot!